# CloudKit: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't get a signing certificate">

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I'm running on simulator and the app works fine, but once on an iPhone device it crashes with - An error occured in discoverUserInfo::

The discoverUserInfo is copied code from Apple's CloudKit sample code below. Is this something on Apple's end, or mine?

```
- (void)discoverUserInfo:(void (^)(CKDiscoveredUserInfo *user))completionHandler {

    [self.container fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID *recordID, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            [self showAlert];
            // In your app, handle this error in an awe-inspiring way.
            NSLog(@"An error occured in %@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
            //abort();
        } else {
            [self.container discoverUserInfoWithUserRecordID:recordID
                                           completionHandler:^(CKDiscoveredUserInfo *user, NSError *error) {
                                               if (error) {
                                                   [self showAlert];
                                                   // In your app, handle this error deftly.
                                                   NSLog(@"An error occured in %@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error);
                                                   //abort();
                                               } else {
                                                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                                                       completionHandler(user);
                                                   });
                                               }
                                           }];
        }
    }];
}
```

The crash logs from the device read:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x31562df0 0x3154e000 + 85488
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e3c92 0x315e0000 + 15506
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x31501934 0x314b8000 + 301364
3   ForCarl                         0x0006dc1a 0x2f000 + 257050
4   UIKit                           0x2643fcc8 0x26095000 + 3845320
5   UIKit                           0x26748cae 0x26095000 + 7027886
6   UIKit                           0x2643fc64 0x26095000 + 3845220
7   UIKit                           0x26438d88 0x26095000 + 3816840
8   UIKit                           0x26439262 0x26095000 + 3818082
9   UIKit                           0x26379a46 0x26095000 + 3033670
10  UIKit                           0x2637bbd2 0x26095000 + 3042258
11  UIKit                           0x261b4f34 0x26095000 + 1179444
12  UIKit                           0x260d88de 0x26095000 + 276702
13  UIKit                           0x260d84f4 0x26095000 + 275700
14  UIKit                           0x260d840a 0x26095000 + 275466
15  QuartzCore                      0x25abdfe2 0x25aa7000 + 94178
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x3145ec6c 0x3145d000 + 7276
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x3146a54e 0x3145d000 + 54606
18  CoreFoundation                  0x22a09884 0x2293a000 + 850052
19  CoreFoundation                  0x22a07fa4 0x2293a000 + 843684
20  CoreFoundation                  0x2295399c 0x2293a000 + 104860
21  CoreFoundation                  0x229537ae 0x2293a000 + 104366
22  GraphicsServices                0x2a3151a4 0x2a30c000 + 37284
23  UIKit                           0x26104630 0x26095000 + 456240
24  ForCarl                         0x0006d996 0x2f000 + 256406
25  libdyld.dylib                   0x3149caac 0x3149b000 + 6828

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3154f24c 0x3154e000 + 4684
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3146f4ec 0x3145d000 + 74988
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3146f21e 0x3145d000 + 74270

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3154f49c 0x3154e000 + 5276
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3154f290 0x3154e000 + 4752
2   CoreFoundation                  0x22a097ee 0x2293a000 + 849902
3   CoreFoundation                  0x22a07db4 0x2293a000 + 843188
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2295399c 0x2293a000 + 104860
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2299d366 0x2293a000 + 406374
6   CoreMotion                      0x23268a26 0x23223000 + 285222
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e2de8 0x315e0000 + 11752
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e2d5a 0x315e0000 + 11610
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0b04 0x315e0000 + 2820

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315639c0 0x3154e000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0e20 0x315e0000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0af8 0x315e0000 + 2808

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315639c0 0x3154e000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0e20 0x315e0000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0af8 0x315e0000 + 2808

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315639c0 0x3154e000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0e20 0x315e0000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0af8 0x315e0000 + 2808

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x315639c0 0x3154e000 + 88512
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0e20 0x315e0000 + 3616
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x315e0af8 0x315e0000 + 2808

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000004
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x33ea39dc      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x001fda68
    r8: 0x00000000    r9: 0x33ea39dc     r10: 0x00000001     r11: 0xc2000000
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x001fda5c      lr: 0x315e3c97      pc: 0x31562df0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
```

Comment: Official Apple  bug case number is 22064324.

Comment: Same problem with one of my users. Have you gotten a response ?

Comment: Apple pointed to the bug number Kevin pointed out above. I didn't change anything in the code, it just started working after a couple days.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Delete** old related profile files.
2. **Generate** or download new profile files.
3. **Install** new profile files.

Answer (score 0):

Try generate new provisioning profile in itunes connect with all certificates you need. Then download them from Xcode preferences, but before doing so, delete the old ones, because it will not be replaced by clicking refresh.

Answer (score 0):

first you have remove provisional profile from Xcode and create new provisional Profile and add then working fine