# CloudKit fails to fetch data from Public Container. Error 1/4000

Tags: ios, iphone, cloudkit, ckerror

I recently deployed an app update with CloudKit support. It has been working fine, and all of sudden I'm starting to get this error:

`Internal Error" (4000); "Couldn't get a signing certificate"`

And my app can't fetch the information from CloudKit.

My provisioning profiles are ok. I changed Apple IDs to check, and none works. I changed iPhone, and still no luck.

Development environment does work on simulator, but not on iPhone.
Obviously production environment can't be fetch from simulator.

The most interesting part is that if I connect my iPhone to Mac, and go to Xcode -> Devices, open my app downloaded from App Store, and read the devices logs, when I attempt to fetch the records, it logs:

`Sep  5 15:26:23 Rogers-6 cloudd[7493] <Error>: We didn't get a Mescal cert back from the server
Sep  5 15:26:23 Rogers-6 cloudd[7493] <Error>: Couldn't renew Mescal session. Failing this request: <CKError 0x12eee3680: "Internal Error" (4000); "Couldn't get a signing certificate">`

I searched for that Mescal error in Google with between quotation marks and got zero results.

There's only one Stack Overflow question regarding this issue:

1. [CloudKit: "Internal Error" (1/4000); "Couldn't get a signing certificate">](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714025/cloudkit-internal-error-1-4000-couldnt-get-a-signing-certificate)
   And it doesn't help.

Last, but most important, it *is* working for some users afaik. A friend of mine has my app installed, and it fetches the data with no problems at all.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

PS: If anyone wants to test and see if it's working for you, my app's named Sueca Drinking Game on the App Store.

Comment: Hi Roger. I've also been having similar issues the last few days. I'm wondering if perhaps Apple are having some issues. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Nope @ChrisVilla, unfortunately not :( And still facing issues.

Comment: Mine seems to spontaneously started working again

Comment: Mine started working again too! Thank you for the "notification" @ChrisVilla! ;) I didn't do anything to change it, and it suddenly started working again.
PS: Still very pissed off with this issue. We rely on an Apple's service (and not on 3rd party's) and they fail to deliver quality. Not really Apple-like. :/

Comment: I still have the same issue. Is anyone else having this issue? It's working in the simulator but not on a device.. :/

Comment: @Prine unfortunately it seems that their system is facing these issues again. Thanks for the heads up, just noticed that mine also isn't working anymore. :/

Answer (score 0):

It seems anyone running iOS 10 trying to access data in a public iCloud database has to have iCloud enabled on their device. I have this issue going on as well and everyone affected has iCloud Drive OFF. I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm afraid this issue experienced by us (at least by me) is completely unrelated to the iOS version, and has nothing to do with iCloud Drive. Explanation: In the past 2 months I haven't changed a bit of code on my app (that is live in the App Store) and the behavior has changed (from working to not working, to working, and now to not working), with no changes on my iCloud Drive settings, or iCloud account, nor iOS upgrades.
I'm facing this issue on my both iDevices, both running iOS 9.3.3, both with the same - or different - Apple IDs (tested) and still no luck. It's 100% Apple's server-side.

Answer (score 0):

September 14th: The problem has been solved. I got this answer by Apple, on my ticket:

> We believe that this issue has been resolved through changes on our side.
>
> If this issue still occurs, please update your bug report with relevant logs, and a test case if possible.

After all, it was really on their side. Hope this information helps.

EDIT (September 30th): I'm facing this issue again. Same diagnosis, no changed made on my side. Filled a new ticket to Apple, I hope it gets resolved soon, since I'm being financially affected by this error :/